# AirBNB style email masking service implementation with AWS Lambda

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am building a small service application where users can cloak their email addresses using the service. Users who register to the website will have a unique email address to communicate with. I have tried to implement this relay service but i am stuck implementing it.

**What i have tried**

- Catch all the emails coming for the domain with SES receiving rules and saving to the s3 bucket
- Trigger lambda function to retrieve the original address of the designated user by calling an api call providing the email address user wanted to contact.
- After a successful call the api call returns the original (unmasked) email address for lambda to forward the email to

Question: Is this an overkill when dealing with 1000s of emails handled like this ? Is there any way that you had implemented such as this ?

*AirBnB style communication

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for the reference, really appreciate it